# Windows font that clearly disambiguates the number ZERO from letter O

Tags: fonts, embed, zero, glyph, system-font

Our intranet web pages need to clearly disambiguate between the letter O and the number ZERO. Is there a screen+printer font that is installed on WindowsXP and Vista that does this either putting a dot inside zero or a slash through it?

If there isn't such a font on the machines themselves, is there a way to embed the font in the page, or some other way for the web page to substitute a glyph for the zero glyph in one of the standard fonts, like Arial?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using [@font-face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font-face#File_formats) you can embed a font into the page so that it will be downloaded as needed. There are a few sites now that will provide fonts to embed, many of them free; one example is [Inconsolata hosted by Google](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Inconsolata).

Comment: Roboto Mono is also great for this - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?preview.text=Auth0

Answer (score 27):

Consolas, which comes with Vista and Windows 7 IIRC, has a slashed zero. It should also come bundled with later versions of MS Office.

You might find one of these other [programming fonts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/revisiting-programming-fonts.html) useful too.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the programming fonts. Consolas not available on XP Pro, though.

Answer (score 7):

The Windows system fonts FixedSys and Terminal have slashes in the zero.

Comment: Terminal is not available on Win XP Pro. FixedSys works OK but has a couple of drawbacks: it cannot go smaller and it gets very jagged when made larger. I forgot to mention cross-browser compatibility in my question: FixedSys works on FF, IE, Opera but not on Chrome or Safari.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The **Terminal** font that comes with Windows XP has that distinction between 0 and O built-in. However, it's not a TrueType font, so I am not sure this fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I remember Terminal. Not available on XP Pro though.

Comment: Huh? Before I posted the above comment, I actually checked on my copy of XP Pro. Did you mean XP Home?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for the font in Word's font-list and it wasn't there; and when you paste text in Terminal font into Word, it seems the font gets converted into something else; the zero glyph is rendered without a slash.

Comment: On Windows 7, I see 5,6,9,12 and 14 options for Terminal. On 5 and 9 I don't see the zero with a stroke.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very nice font here called [Anonymous](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymous.html) - credit to Mark Simonson for his work... easy on the eye... also, there's Bitstream Vera Sans, another type...

Comment: Thanks for the link to Anonymous. Yes, easy on the eyes, and free, which will please the powers-that-be.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Unicode character Ø, U+00D8: Latin Capital Letter O With Stroke. If you can substitute that character it works in Arial and probably most other Windows fonts.

Comment: Although that could make for some unexpected results if the user tries to copy and paste such text.

Comment: @Josh, if copy and pasting were the solution it wouldn't be so important to distinguish the characters. But I see your point.

Comment: It does have to be an actual ZERO codepoint because our users do sometimes cut data from the screen and paste into other systems, but often they're just writing down by hand what they see on the screen or reading it out to someone on the other end of the phone. We are using several crazy-quilt legacy systems, and the migration "strategy" to the new system is lunacy. If the luddite owner of the company had his druthers, users would be tracking data by writing it on the palms of their hands.

Comment: @Tim, oh well it was worth a shot. Maybe this answer will work for somebody else some day.

Answer (score 0):

slashed zero fonts: consolas, cascadia (and its variations,) source code